# Wrap widget in flutter with a min size for children, expanded otherwise

Tags: flutter

I have a wrap widget with some form fields in it like so for my most recent attempt with constrained box:

```
Wrap(
        children: [
          ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 100),
            child: createTextField(
              context,
              'Ref. Company (Insurer)',
              'reference_company',
              initialValue: widget.form.referenceCompany ?? '',
              onChange: (val) => widget.form.referenceCompany = val,
              enabled: bo.insurerInfo.insurer.isNullOrEmpty(),
              // expanded: true,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 4),
          ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 100),
            child: createTextField(
              context,
              'Community Id',
              'community_id',
              initialValue: widget.form.communityId ?? '',
              onChange: (val) => widget.form.communityId = val,
              // expanded: true,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 4),
          ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 100),
            child: createTextField(
              context,
              'Community Name',
              'community_name',
              initialValue: widget.form.communityName ?? '',
              onChange: (val) => widget.form.communityName = val,
              // expanded: true,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )
```

This will render the form fields on separate lines with an expanded width.

I want this to happen on smaller devices (perhaps a phone) and for larger devices, I want them to be on a single line (perhaps an iPad). For in-between devices I want the fields to be able to have a minWidth and if all three won't fit, I want the first two two render on the first line with expanded widths and the third to render on the second line as expandned.

I have a great deal of forms to create and varying sizes and widths where it needs to work on multiple device sizes. I am working alone and am a little stuck on how to do this.

see this image for details on what I want:
[image]

EDIT:
I recently found pub.dev/packages/flex_list Which is close to what I want, however I can't use a TextField as a child it seems since it does not implement the computeDryLayout method... I can't find a way around that yet. Wrapping it in a Container or SizedBox does not work to give it a width.

EDIT: got it working in my answer below with some workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [flex_list](https://pub.dev/packages/flex_list) package may be used here with some modifications.

The FlexList will space each element just like a wrap might, but will then expand each element to completely fill up a row. The caveat here is that each element needs to implement a computeDryLayout method, which a TextField does not.

A workaround to this is to wrap each TextField in a render object that use the child's intrinsic dimensions instead of invoking the child's dry layout method. see [this github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71687#issuecomment-753549590) for a discussion around the topic.

the object we need to wrap each text field may be added to the project like so:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

/// NOTE ref: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71687 & https://gist.github.com/matthew-carroll/65411529a5fafa1b527a25b7130187c6
/// Same as `IntrinsicWidth` except that when this widget is instructed
/// to `computeDryLayout()`, it doesn't invoke that on its child, instead
/// it computes the child's intrinsic width.
///
/// This widget is useful in situations where the `child` does not
/// support dry layout, e.g., `TextField` as of 01/02/2021.
class DryIntrinsicWidth extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const DryIntrinsicWidth({Key? key, Widget? child}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  RenderDryIntrinsicWidth createRenderObject(BuildContext context) => RenderDryIntrinsicWidth();
}

class RenderDryIntrinsicWidth extends RenderIntrinsicWidth {
  @override
  Size computeDryLayout(BoxConstraints constraints) {
    if (child != null) {
      final width = child!.computeMinIntrinsicWidth(constraints.maxHeight);
      final height = child!.computeMinIntrinsicHeight(width);
      return Size(width, height);
    } else {
      return Size.zero;
    }
  }
}

/// NOTE ref: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/71687 & https://gist.github.com/matthew-carroll/65411529a5fafa1b527a25b7130187c6
/// Same as `IntrinsicHeight` except that when this widget is instructed
/// to `computeDryLayout()`, it doesn't invoke that on its child, instead
/// it computes the child's intrinsic height.
///
/// This widget is useful in situations where the `child` does not
/// support dry layout, e.g., `TextField` as of 01/02/2021.
class DryIntrinsicHeight extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const DryIntrinsicHeight({Key? key, Widget? child}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  RenderDryIntrinsicHeight createRenderObject(BuildContext context) => RenderDryIntrinsicHeight();
}

class RenderDryIntrinsicHeight extends RenderIntrinsicHeight {
  @override
  Size computeDryLayout(BoxConstraints constraints) {
    if (child != null) {
      final height = child!.computeMinIntrinsicHeight(constraints.maxWidth);
      final width = child!.computeMinIntrinsicWidth(height);
      return Size(width, height);
    } else {
      return Size.zero;
    }
  }
}
```

Now with these new objects we can use the same given list like below. Instead of a flex factor, the width of each SizedBox may be used to make it behave similar to a flex on an Expanded object.

(e.x. width of 200 and 400 would be like a flex of 1 and 2)

```
FlexList(
            verticalSpacing: 0,
            horizontalSpacing: 4,
            children: [
              DryIntrinsicWidth(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 400,
                  child: createTextField(
                    context,
                    'Ref. Company (Insurer)',
                    'reference_company',
                    initialValue: widget.form.referenceCompany ?? '',
                    onChange: (val) => widget.form.referenceCompany = val,
                    enabled: bo.insurerInfo.insurer.isNullOrEmpty(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              DryIntrinsicWidth(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 200,
                  child: createTextField(
                    context,
                    'Community Id',
                    'community_id',
                    initialValue: widget.form.communityId ?? '',
                    onChange: (val) => widget.form.communityId = val,
                    // expanded: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              DryIntrinsicWidth(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: 200,
                  child: createTextField(
                    context,
                    'Community Name',
                    'community_name',
                    initialValue: widget.form.communityName ?? '',
                    onChange: (val) => widget.form.communityName = val,
                    // expanded: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Note: The width on the SizedBox is treated like a minWidth and this will be expanded by the FlexList if more space is available.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try a layout builder

```
      class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyHomePage({super.key});
    
      @override
      State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
    }
    
    class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
            return Center(
//remove padding if u don't want the border around the page....
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30.0),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    const SizedBox(height: 20),
                    if (constraints.maxWidth >= 768) ...[
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextFormField(
                              decoration: inputDecoration(),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 4),
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextFormField(
                              decoration: inputDecoration(),
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 4),
                          Expanded(
                            child: TextFormField(
                              decoration: inputDecoration(),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ] else ...[
                      Column(
                        children: [
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration: inputDecoration(),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration: inputDecoration(),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),
                          TextFormField(
                            decoration: inputDecoration(),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ]
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
        );
      }
    
      InputDecoration inputDecoration() {
        return const InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder:
                OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.green)));
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for. I don't want to have to hard code any device widths and what not. 

I just found https://pub.dev/packages/flex_list Which is close to what I want, however I can't use a TextField as a child it seems since it does not implement the computeDryLayout method... I can't find a way around that yet.